# UIPageViewController different behavior between swipe and tap

Tags: ios

I'm experiencing a strange behavior with a `UIPageViewController` in my project.
I implemented the `viewControllerBeforeViewController` and `viewControllerAfterViewController` methods and they work fine when I swipe the finger in the PageViewController.
I also want the pages to turn when the user taps on the left and right area of the PageViewController, as it happens on iBook.

When the user taps on one of the corners the correct method (`viewControllerAfterViewController` or `viewControllerBeforeViewController`) is called, and I return a valid `UIViewController` as I do when the user swipes between the pages.
Unfortunately after the tap gesture the page is not turned and the `didFinishAnimating` method is not called. If, after a tap, I perform a swipe gesture the page turns with the curl animation but only the `didFinishAnimating` delegate method is called.

Pretty weird, isn't it? It seems like `UIPageViewController` already loaded the viewcontroller, but doesn't start the animation until I perform a swipe gesture.

One possibile solution to my problem would be to detect the swipe and tap gesture, do nothing in the delegate methods and turn the pages via `setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion`.

It's not a problem for me to detect the gesture since I do it already on my project, but I want to understand why `UIPageViewController` behaves in such a strange way

Thank you!

Comment: I found the solution.
I implemented gestureRecognizerShouldBegin, I set my viewcontroller to be the delegate for the TapGestureRecognizer of my PageViewController and I always returned YES. Now I can use the tap and the swipe to navigate through pages.

Comment: Make it an answer to vote up for this! THANKS GUY!

Answer (score 0):

This may be an associated problem, but it is quite similar so perhaps it deserves mentioning here. Sometimes when setting up a UIPageViewController you will find that the reverse gestures (previous page) of tap and swipe both work, but with forward gestures (next page) the swipe works but not the tap.

This is typically because the bounds of the root UIView of the UIViewController in which the UIPageViewController is nested have not been correctly set. You need to remember to explicitly set those bounds, typically to the bounds of the device. For example on the iPad:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 768.0, 1024.0)] ;
```

Comment: Add tags to your question, what version etc would be helpful.